# Convert nested Array -> arrays -> object TO Array -> Object => object value : object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object, reduce

In the data below. I would like to get it an object with some of the values as keys , like this:

**FROM HERE:** link to the whole data [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6xxpgn-w95mpz?file=app%2Fgrid%2Fgrid.component.ts) (this.localObject)

```
const employees = [{
    "EmployeeID": "100A",
    "FirstName": "Downs",
    "aval": [
       {"start": "11-19", "end": "2", "ava": "30", "health": "4"},
       {"start": "11-20", "end": "2", "ava": "40", "health": "4"},
       {"start": "11-21", "end": "2", "ava": "50", "health": "4"},
       {"start": "11-22", "end": "2", "ava": "60", "health": "4"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "EmployeeID": "100B",
    "FirstName": "Mckenzie",
    "aval": [
       {"start": "11-19", "end": "2", "ava": "1", "health": "4"},
       {"start": "11-20", "end": "2", "ava": "2", "health": "4"},
       {"start": "11-21", "end": "2", "ava": "3", "health": "4"},
       {"start": "11-22", "end": "2", "ava": "4", "health": "4"}
    ]
  },
]
```

**TO HERE:**

```
const employees = [
   { "EmployeeID": "100A", "11-19": "30"},
   { "EmployeeID": "100A", "11-20": "40"},
   { "EmployeeID": "100A", "11-21": "50"},
   { "EmployeeID": "100A", "11-22": "60"},
   { "EmployeeID": "100B", "11-19": "1"},
   { "EmployeeID": "100B", "11-20": "2"},
   { "EmployeeID": "100B", "11-21": "3"},
   { "EmployeeID": "100B", "11-22": "4"}
]

//and so on...
```

So far I've tried:

```
this.localData = this.localObject.employees;
const firstLevel = this.localData.map(x => x.aval);
```

firsLevel will give me an array of objects which is closer to what I need, now I need to put the **"start"** value as a key and the **"ava"** value as a value property inside their own object containers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to iterate the inner arrays as well and build a single array.

```js
var array = [{ EmployeeID: "100A", FirstName: "Downs", aval: [{ start: "11-19", end: "2", ava: "30", health: "4" }, { start: "11-20", end: "2", ava: "40", health: "4" }, { start: "11-21", end: "2", ava: "50", health: "4" }, { start: "11-22", end: "2", ava: "60", health: "4" }] }, { EmployeeID: "100B", FirstName: "Mckenzie", aval: [{ start: "11-19", end: "2", ava: "1", health: "4" }, { start: "11-20", end: "2", ava: "2", health: "4" }, { start: "11-21", end: "2", ava: "3", health: "4" }, { start: "11-22", end: "2", ava: "4", health: "4" }] }],
    result = array.reduce((r, { EmployeeID, aval }) => [
        ...r,
        ...aval.map(({ start, ava }) => ({ EmployeeID, [start]: ava }))
    ], []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nice, may I ask any good sources to learn reduce() ?. it's not my forte

Comment: you could start here: [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), but i have no other resource than this. just try often to use it ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.flatMap` and iterate over the `aval` inside it  using `Array.map`like below

```js
const employees = [{
    "EmployeeID": "100A",
    "FirstName": "Downs",
    "aval": [
       {"start": "11-19", "end": "2", "ava": "30", "health": "4"},
       {"start": "11-20", "end": "2", "ava": "40", "health": "4"},
       {"start": "11-21", "end": "2", "ava": "50", "health": "4"},
       {"start": "11-22", "end": "2", "ava": "60", "health": "4"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "EmployeeID": "100B",
    "FirstName": "Mckenzie",
    "aval": [
       {"start": "11-19", "end": "2", "ava": "1", "health": "4"},
       {"start": "11-20", "end": "2", "ava": "2", "health": "4"},
       {"start": "11-21", "end": "2", "ava": "3", "health": "4"},
       {"start": "11-22", "end": "2", "ava": "4", "health": "4"}
    ]
  },
]

let res = employees.flatMap(({ EmployeeID, aval }) => 
                    aval.map(({ start, ava }) => ({ EmployeeID, [start]: ava })))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: it looks like, you are a great fan of `flatMap` which does not work actually in edge ...

Comment: Oh yes I am (after understanding it's power). Given 'Edge' case, I doubt it supports other ESNext features as well at least some. But we should never miss any new feature because of just Edge. :)

Comment: man, I love this answer, but the framework I'm using has a problem with ES6 and doesnt play well with FlatMap, they are working on the solution tho

Comment: No problem @brohymn. :)

Comment: nice one... `flatMap` is trivial to polyfill

Comment: Correct @georg.